# laravel whereHas in relationships "where not working"

Tags: php, laravel

i need help for Laravel 4.2

the models are:
//1. model kelengkapan

```
class Kelengkapan extends Eloquent{

    public function detilKelengkapan(){
        return $this->hasMany('DetilKelengkapan', 'id_kelengkapan');
    }       
}
```

// 2. model DetilKelengkapan

```
class DetilKelengkapan extends Eloquent{

    public function tDetilKelengkapanPaket(){
        return $this->hasMany('TDetilKelengkapanPaket', 'id_detil_kelengkapan');
    }

    public function kelengkapan(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Kelengkapan', 'id_kelengkapan');
    }


}
```

// 3. model TDetilKelengkapanPaket

```
class TDetilKelengkapanPaket extends Eloquent{

        public function detilKelengkapan(){
            return $this->belongsTo('DetilKelengkapan', 'id_detil_kelengkapan');
        }

    }
```

the controller is:

```
$kelengkapan = Kelengkapan::with('detilKelengkapan.tDetilKelengkapanPaket')
                            ->whereHas('detilKelengkapan.tDetilKelengkapanPaket', function($q) use ($id){
                                $q->where('id_paket', $paket);
                            })->get();
```

but the result has not filtering by "id_paket" but showed all data. thanks. (newbie)

Answer (score 3):

**Your Code:**

```
$kelengkapan = Kelengkapan::with('detilKelengkapan.tDetilKelengkapanPaket')
                        ->whereHas('detilKelengkapan.tDetilKelengkapanPaket', function($q) use ($id){
                            $q->where('id_paket', $paket);
                        })->get();
```

**The correct Code:**

```
$kelengkapan = Kelengkapan::with('detilKelengkapan.tDetilKelengkapanPaket')
                        ->whereHas('detilKelengkapan.tDetilKelengkapanPaket', function($q) use ($id){
                            //the function should return the $q variable.
                            return $q->where('id_paket', $id);
                        })->get();
```

**Explanation:**

`whereHas` function has 2 compulsory arguments. A relationship function name, and a closure. The closure must `return` a `query` object so that filters can be chained.

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations

Answer (score 0):

In there whereHas function you pass `$id` variable in the closure but you are using `$packet` inside.

```
$kelengkapan = Kelengkapan::with('detilKelengkapan.tDetilKelengkapanPaket')
                            ->whereHas('detilKelengkapan.tDetilKelengkapanPaket', function($q) use ($id){
                                $q->where('id_paket', $id);
                                //---------------------^
                            })->get();
```

Try it and let me know the result.